# Extremely slow MySQL database connection

Tags: android, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm developing an app for android where I make a direct connection with MySQL server using JDBC connector. Originally I used the oldest JDBC connector since it was recommended, but I couldn't execute procedure CALLS statements with that connector, so I switched on to the newest (5.1.19 JDBC connector). Here executing those queries is possible, but the connection to the server is extremely slow (about 15 seconds compared to about 2-3 seconds with the oldest connector). Here is my connection code:

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://00.00.00.00/dbname"
                        ,"user" ,"pass");
        if (connect != null){
            System.out.println("CONNECTION SUCCEED");
```

The ip and other values in the connection string are different for security reasons you see. Any ideas? Help greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JDBC driver that's compatible with your version of MySQL.

I'd recommend pooling your database connections.  The cost of creating one will be spread out over all your requests that way.